# Relational Algebra SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

Hello everyone i was wondering if i could get some help with a problem

Postimi(status)(Post_ID:integer,user_ID:integer,test:string, data:date,time:integer)

I need to fing the Relational Algebra related to Postimi

the question is

List users who posted two or more statuses yesterday while today have not posted any statuses?

if someone could help me.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your (home)work. Show what you can do & explain re where you are stuck. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. For code questions give a [mre], PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "translate"/"convert"--Same result? Same structure? How does an SQL table correspond to a relation--what if a table has duplicate rows or nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select yd.user_ID
from status yd -- yd for yesterday
where yd.date = current_date() - interval 1 day
and not exists (
  select *
  from status td -- td for today
  where td.user_ID = yd.user_ID
    and td.date = current_date()
)
group by yd.user_ID
having count(*) >= 2
```

Or

```
select user_ID
from status
where date >= current_date() - interval 1 day
  and date <= current_date()
group by user_ID
having count(*) >= 2
   and max(date) < current_date()
```